# configuring apache alias and subdomains vhost

Tags: apache

I have mydomain.com, and I have created 2websites, one wih wymfony2, and the other with wordpress.

```
admin.mydomain.com => symfony2 website
www.mydomain.com => wordpress website
mydomain.com => redirect on www.mydomain.com
```

My wordpress has an iframe, and due to security raison, admin.mydomain.com can not talk with www.mydomain.com. Which cause me serious problem (for curious people, I play with url anchor like gmail does to go to a specific page in this iframe when you share a link)

The advantage of symfony2 is it doesn't care of the url. It works everywhere.
How could I create an alias for:

```
www.mydomain.com/administration => symfony2 website
```

I tried a lot of things, but the best result I had was a 403error on this new url.